# Making a Generic UserControl which can be accessed by other view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, mvvm-foundation

I have UserControl A given below with two Radio Buttons.
This UserControl view has its ViewModel.

**Question:**
I again have two Views Create and Edit.
I want to use the above mentioned UserControl within Create/Edit with requirement that i can make the radiobuttons or any of the elements in UserControl to be Visible or Hidden based on the requirement in Create/Edit View.

*Eg: Create May not require Radio button 1 and 2.So only Rectangle must be displayed.*
Whatever input i give in the list or textbox must be updated in UserControl's ViewModel and the search result after clicking on button must be sent to Create/Edit accordingly.
Note:Create/Edit have their own ViewModels.Please suggest which approach is best considering MVVM

The Control has to be placed in the grayed out area as shown in rectangle for Create/Edit View

[image: Search Control]

[image: Create,Edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create DependancyProperty inside your UserControl like

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RadioButtonVisibilityProperty= 
 DependencyProperty.Register( "RadioButtonVisibility", typeof(Visibility),
 typeof(MyUserControl));


public Visibility RadioButtonVisibility 
{
    get { return (Visibility)GetValue(RadioButtonVisibilityProperty); }
    set { SetValue(RadioButtonVisibilityProperty, value); }
}
```

and inside your UserControl's xaml Set the radiobutton's visibility like

```
<RadioButton Visibility="{Binding Parent.RadioButtonVisibility,ElementName=LayoutRoot}"/>
```

and in your main View(Create/Edit) do like this

```
<MyUserControl x:Name="Edit" RadioButtonVisibility="Visible"/>
```

or

```
<MyUserControl x:Name="Create" RadioButtonVisibility="Hidden"/>
```

And dont forget to give your UserControl's parent Grid the name "LayoutRoot"

like

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to have the `UserControl` be driven by some abstract `BaseViewModel`. Then you create two sub-classes `EditViewModel` and `CreateViewModel` which you then use based on the context.

Quick crude example for the radio buttons:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
  public bool ShowRadioButtons { get; protected set; }
}

public class EditViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
  public EditViewModel()
  {
    ShowRadioButtons = true;
  }
}

public class CreateViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
  public CreateViewModel()
  {
    ShowRadioButtons = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information...Adding to the above question..I want the above control to be consumed by the views in the application without reusing the code..This control will be used as a generic one